# How can I decrease input height with floating labels?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

How can I decrease input height with floating label? I tried putting size but it didn't work.

```
<Col xs={5} md={2}>
  <FloatingLabel
      size="sm"
      controlId="floatingInput"
      label="Cod do Produto"
      className="mb-2 "
      style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}
  >

    <Form.Control type={"text"}
        size="sm"
        value={InputCodigo}
        name={"Data"}
        onChange={(e) => setInputCodigo(e.target.value)}
        autoComplete={'off'}
        placeholder={"Cod do Produto"} />
  </FloatingLabel>
</Col>
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll probably need some [custom CSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html), which should probably be applied globally for consistency. Something like this should do. It reduces the input height from 58px to 42px.

```css
.form-floating>.form-control,
.form-floating>.form-control-plaintext {
  padding: 0rem 0.75rem;
}

.form-floating>.form-control,
.form-floating>.form-control-plaintext,
.form-floating>.form-select {
  height: calc(2.5rem + 2px);
  line-height: 1;
}

.form-floating>label {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
}
```

[image]

FYI, all I did for this solution is inspect the [official demo](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/floating-labels/#floating-labels) and play with the styles until I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget add !important in the final of the each property to override the Bootstrap properties:

```css
.form-floating>.form-control,
.form-floating>.form-control-plaintext {
  padding: 0rem 0.75rem !important;
}

.form-floating>.form-control,
.form-floating>.form-control-plaintext,
.form-floating>.form-select {
  height: calc(2.5rem + 2px) !important;
  line-height: 1 !important;
}

.form-floating>label {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem !important;
}
```

Comment: This should only be done where necessary, and specificity overrides are a better strategy.