# bootstrap floating label doesn't work with different form-control sizes?

Tags: bootstrap-5

floating label works fine with form-control, but using form-control-lg (example) is not going to work.

so all in all

this will work

```html
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Email">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
```

this will work, but the input size stays the same

```html
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                    placeholder="Email">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
```

this will not work, but the input size changes

```html
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control-lg"
                    placeholder="Email">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
```

so the question:
is there a way to have a "large input" and floating label on it?

Comment: no, it's hardcoded: [Issue with Hardcoded Height of Form-Controls in Bootstrap 5's Floating Labels](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/38456), maybe try customize yourself, example: [How can I decrease input height with floating labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72391908/how-can-i-decrease-input-height-with-floating-labels)

Comment: I see. I'll probably go with Tailwind then. Write this as a reply and I'll mark it as answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment (v5.3), [floating labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/) size is hardcoded, and also latest Github issues mentioning it are closed with "not planned" reason:

[Issue with Hardcoded Height of Form-Controls in Bootstrap 5's Floating Labels #38456](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/38456)

Workaround is to adjust code manually, examples:

- [How can I decrease input height with floating labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72391908/how-can-i-decrease-input-height-with-floating-labels)
- [Add floating labels sizing #32584](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/32584)